# What is the purpose of the soundEffectsEnabled view attribute in Android?

Tags: android, android-studio

What is the use of the the view attribute `soundEffectsEnabled` (Boolean) as seen in Android Studio properties panel?

[image: soundEffectsEnabled button set to true]

I tried setting it to true for a Button as seen in the image above, for getting a click sound when the button is clicked, but it had no effect. I looked up the documentation for the attribute at the link given below but it does not seem to be descriptive enough.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#attr_android:soundEffectsEnabled

I understand that I can try to add sound effects by updating the onClickListener for the button and adding media resources, but I wanted to understand what the purpose of the `soundEffectsEnabled` attribute is, and how it can be useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:

Setting the `soundEffectsEnabled` attribute of the view to `true` is required for enabling the click sound. However, two other things need to be done apart from this:

1. Make a function call to `View.playSoundEffect()` in the `onClickListner` of the view to produce a sound, as follows:

```
      fun setListenerForButton(button: Button) {      
            button.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener{
                override fun onClick(v: View?) {
                    v?.playSoundEffect(android.view.SoundEffectConstants.CLICK)
                    // Other functionality as required goes here
                }
            })
      }
```

2. Enable sounds (and possibly haptic feedback) upon touch in your device settings. Generally this can be found in a place like `Settings -> Sound -> (Advanced ->) Touch sounds`